# R's toTitleCase() not working on word "all"

Tags: r

For some reason R's `toTitleCase()` function isn't working on the word "all". Any ideas why?

```
library(tools)
toTitleCase("all")  # gives "all"
toTitleCase("alt")  # gives "Alt"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Details section in the help page `?toTitleCase` notes that

> Generally words in all capitals are left alone: this implementation knows about conventional mixed-case words such as ‘LaTeX’ and ‘OpenBUGS’ and a few technical terms which are not usually capitalized such as ‘jar’ and ‘xls’.

Type `toTitleCase` without parentheses into your console. You will see the sets of excepted words along with a lengthy regex for connector words. Among these is

```
either <- c("all", "above", "after", "along", "also", "among", 
        "any", "both", "can", "few", "it", "less", "log", "many", 
        "may", "more", "over", "some", "their", "then", "this", 
        "under", "until", "using", "von", "when", "where", "which", 
        "will", "without", "yet", "you", "your")
```

which contains "all".

Comment: Does seem strange that the `either` words aren't capitalized even if they are the first word, where as the `lp` matching regex (which includes things like "a", "an", "for") will be capitalized if first. `toTitleCase("for all") [1] "For all"` but `toTitleCase("all for") [1] "all for"` seems inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, that does seem inconsistent. Arguably, the first word should always be capitalized and the distinction between these sets isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: I see the value in not capitalizing technical terms even if they are first, which is dealt with in yet another case, `alone`. But I agree that the the regex-identified words in `lpat` and the words in `either` seem like they should be treated the same.